# SQL Query - Order by issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

When i have duplicate orders in table, the data displays like below. All header records first and then all line records for that particular order.

```
OrderNo     Column1  
300         Header   
300         Header   
300         Line   
300         Line    
200         Header  
200         Line  
200         Line
```

Expected output:

```
OrderNo     Column1  
300         Header  
300         Line  
300         Header  
300         Line   
200         Header  
200         Line  
200         Line
```

I need to export this data in excel file. SO i need a proper sequence of records,i.e. Order1,Header,Line then Order2 Header,Line
How can i achieve this using sql?

Comment: And which header belongs to which line?  Remember there is no default order in SQL.

Comment: This is just a sample data of two columns. there are many more columns with more details. Every order is going to have one header and multiple line records. OrderNo is the key in the table.

Comment: But in your example every order can have multiple headers

Comment: If there is only one Header then you can just do `order by orderNo, Column1` since alphabetically H comes before L

Comment: Each order can have only one header. When you see multiple headers, it is the duplicate record set of a header and line.

Comment: @juergen We need to consider each order as a separate entity irrespective of being duplicate. the header and line records should show back to back per order. Instead, now it shows 2 header records for orderno 300 then 2 line records for orderno 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interleave the headers and lines using `row_number()` in the `order by` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
order by orderno,
         row_number() over (partition by orderno, column1 order by ?);
```

The `?` is for whatever column determines the final ordering among the rows.  If you don't care, you can just use `orderno`.

Comment: Thanks you for the solution. However it partially solved my problem. for the duplicate order, the sequence is header,line,line,header.    Instead, it should be header,line,header,line

Comment: @Dimple . . . It should be interleaved.